# Create list of items specific to the session user in PHP

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, session, controller

I would like to create a list from my database via PHP (I use CodeIgniter).

Here's my database :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `flux_demo` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
USE `flux_demo`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Login` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Mail` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Bio` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Register Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Last Activity` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Thumbnail` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`people_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Project` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Thumbnail` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Start Date` date NOT NULL,
  `End Date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assigned_projects_ppeople` (
  `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`people_id`,`project_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (people_id) REFERENCES people (people_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES projects (project_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

As you can see, I use a many-to-many table to make the relationship between projects and people.
In CodeIgniter, I use the session class to store session data ('id', 'Name', 'Login', 'Thumbnail').
My view page is a simple list using ul and li tags.

```
<?php 
    $this->load->model('project_model');
    $this->project_model->getProjectsForUser();
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($result as $r)
    {
        echo "<li><a href=http://www.domain.com/$r->Project>$r->Project</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

My question is how can I create the list matching with the session user ?
My uri segments will be : http://domain.com/project_name

REEDIT : I created the model :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Project_model extends CI_Model{

    public function getProjectsForUser()
{
    $query = $this->db->query(
            'SELECT r.project_id, r.Project
            FROM assigned_projects_ppeople a JOIN people p
            ON a.people_id = p.people_id JOIN projects r
            ON a.project_id = r.project_id
            GROUP BY r.project_id, r.Project'
            );
    $data = $query->row_array();
    return $data;
}
}
?>
```

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Try something yourself first and then ask what is not working.It's not the way to ask questions.

Comment: Done ;) But still doesn't work, CodeIgniter said there was a problem line "$this->project_model->getProjectsForUser();" in my view but I don't know what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeed. Once finished, we understand it was not difficult.

Here is my function to query my database :

```
public function getProjectsForUser()
    {
        $login_id = $this->session->userdata('User_id');
        $this->db->select('Project');
        $this->db->from('assigned_projects_ppeople a');
        $this->db->where('people_id', $login_id);
        $this->db->join('projects r', 'r.project_id = a.project_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query;
    }
```

Then, I definited the variable in my controller page :

```
$this->load->model('project_model');
$query = $this->project_model->getProjectsForUser();
$args['available_projects'] = $query->result();
$this->load->view('home', $args);
```

And the final code to insert in my view page was :

```
<?php
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($available_projects as $r)
    {
        echo '<li><a href="'.base_url($r->Project).'">'.$r->Project.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

I have to define how I can use a URI like that :

```
http://localhost/project/project_id
```

I think is like blog method, so I'm gonna study it.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: One small thing I would add : Dont return the `result response` : `return $query;`, instead return the results directly from the model function like this:  `return $query->result();` OR `return $query->result_array();` depending on your choice and assign it directly to the controller variable : `$args['available_projects'] = $this->project_model->getProjectsForUser();`.
Cheers, and best of luck. :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in model so that returns the al the records of projects from database

```
 $response=$this->yourmodel->model_function();
```

Then try to loop the resultant data in the ul as

```
 echo "ul";

 foreach($response as $projectData)
{
echo "<li><a href=http://www.domain.com/$projectData->Project>$projectData->Project</a></li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: I made this in the view page, but there's a problem with the line $response=$this->yourmodel->model_function(); when I test it. I also load the model page using $this->load->model('yourmodel');